# Pandas-python: dataframe split to new row after a specific string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains the a list of people with the items that they have. example:

```
Name        Family      Member      Items
Phil        abr          no          item1 -- item2 -- item3
John        fds          yes         item -- item2
```

I want to split the column of Items where each string after the '--' goes to a new line. So I want my output like this :

```
Name        Family      Member      Items
Phil        abr          no          item1
Phil        abr          no          item2
Phil        abr          no          item3
John        fds          yes         item
John        fds          yes         item2
```

Is it feasable ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check with `split` then `explode`

```
df = df.assign(Items=df['Items'].str.split(' -- ')).explode('Items')
df
Out[15]: 
   Name Family Member  Items
0  Phil    abr     no  item1
0  Phil    abr     no  item2
0  Phil    abr     no  item3
1  John    fds    yes   item
1  John    fds    yes  item2
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @jm1701 try update your pandas, explode is after 0.25 ~